# Check for file and process it, existence of file launch script - perl

Tags: perl, file, events

How can I write a Perl program that will wait for an input file to be created and then process the contents of that file? Ideally this should be a cross-platform solution rather than relying on features of a given operating system.

Note that the file might exist as soon as the script is started, or it might only be created at a later date. Once the input file has been processed the Perl program can exit.

[Note that this is a substantially edited version of the original question. The original poster should feel free to make additional edits if I didn't properly understand the question.]

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid you need to expand on your question. In particular - what are you trying to accomplish? The answer is 'probably' but you won't get a useful answer without fleshing our your question a bit more.

Comment: What platform are you working on?

Comment: so far i had created perl script which wile extract information from xml file.Which works fine. But the file is not alwyas existing. I need something that will tell my script to run now because the file which he is about to process and continue.

Comment: What platform are you working on?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [File::Monitor](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Monitor). It will inform you of all sorts of file system events. This program shows how to monitor file creation in a specific directory and process all new XML files.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use File::Monitor;

my $monitor = File::Monitor->new;

$monitor->watch( {
  name        => 'E:\Perl\source',
  files       => 1,
  callback    => { files_created => \&files_created }
} );

while () {
  my @new = $monitor->scan;
  sleep 1;
}

sub files_created {
  my ($name, $event, $change) = @_;
  for my $file ( $change->files_created ) {
    process_xml($file) if $file =~ /\.xml$/i;
  }
}

sub process_xml {
  my ($file) = @_;
  say $file;
}
```